# Can not add web service reference to my project using port number

Tags: c#, web-services, port-number

I can access `serverIP:7075//webservice` from a web browser but I cannot add it to Visual Studio. It throws an exception.

Comment: It should work. What kind of web service is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try appending `?wsdl` at the end of the URL when adding a reference in Visual Studio

Eg:

```
serverIP:7075/webservice?wsdl
```

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2012:

`Add Service Reference...`, type or paste in the `Address`, click `Go`, select it and click `OK`.